# Get maximum value of a GROUP BY query without subquery in mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate

i have some queries which group datasets and count them, e.g.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM `table`
GROUP BY `column`
```

now i have the number of rows for which `column` is the same, so far so good.

problem is: how do i get the aggregate (min/max/avg/sum) values for those “grouped” counts. using a subquery sure is the easiest, but i was wondering if this is possible within this single query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `min` and `max` you can `ORDER BY` and fetch the first row. For `sum`/`avg`/other aggregates you would need a subquery.

Comment: if i’m using `ORDER BY COUNT(*) LIMIT 1` i could be using a subquery too ;) and i _guess_ ordering is slower than subquerying. so there is no way to do this without subquery (for other aggregates)?

Comment: I don't think ordering is slower than subquery in this case. Neither it is faster :) And now, you can't aggregate aggregates without putting on another layer.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you should be able to do this all at once.  My tests seem to indicate that this works.

```
| date       | hits |
|-------------------|
| 2009-10-10 |    3 |
| 2009-10-10 |    6 |
| 2009-10-10 |    1 |
| 2009-10-10 |    3 |
| 2009-10-11 |   12 |
| 2009-10-11 |    4 |
| 2009-10-11 |    8 |
 -------------------

SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(hits), SUM(hits) FROM table GROUP BY date

| COUNT(*)  | MAX(hits) |
|-----------|-----------|
|        4  |         6 |
|        3  |        12 |
 -----------------------
```

SUM, MIN and AVG also work.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nah, if I understand the question correctly, he wants like sum of counts and minimum maximum number of hits.

Comment: no, i’m sorry. with your example table i want to get 4 as `MAX(COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

```
| date       | hits |
|-------------------|
| 2009-10-10 |    3 |
| 2009-10-10 |    6 |
| 2009-10-10 |    1 |
| 2009-10-10 |    3 |
| 2009-10-11 |   12 |
| 2009-10-11 |    4 |
| 2009-10-11 |    8 |
```

I think knittl was trying to do something like this:

```
select min(hits), max(hits), avg(hits), sum(hits)<br>
from table
group by date
```